# get data from array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I'm trying to get the data from array in my controller php on Cakephp.

I have this function:

```
public function updateUserStatus() {

  if(isset($this->params['url']["pcs"]))  {

    $uus = array( "pcs" =>$this->params['url']["pcs"] );
    $trans = $this->Transaction->updateUserStatus($uus);

  } else {
    $trans = "failed";
  }

  $this->set('trans', $trans);
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

And I want to get the data from `status_id` who have this response:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array 
    ( 
    [status_id] => 2 
    ) 
[1] => Array 
    ( 
    [rem_time] => 66 
    ) 
)
```

How can I do it?
My question is how can i get the data for status_id ?

Comment: my question is how can i get the data for status_id

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateUserStatus() {
    if (isset($this->params['url']["pcs"]))  {
        $uus = array("pcs" =>$this->params['url']["pcs"]);
        $trans = $this->Transaction->updateUserStatus($uus);
    } else {
        $trans = "failed";
    }

    $currentStatus = 0;
    if (is_array($trans) && isset($trans['status_id'])) {
        $currentStatus = $trans['status_id'];
    }

    $this->set('trans', $trans);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

---

```
public function updateUserStatus($uus){
    if(isset($uus["pcs"])) {
        $sql = "SELECT status_id  as status_id , rem_time as rem_time FROM phones WHERE pcs = '".$uus["pcs"]."' LIMIT 1";
        $query = $this->query($sql);
        return $query[0]['phones'];
    } else {
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

Notice, we are returning `$query[0]['phones']`.

Let me know if it works.
The code could also use some refactoring.

For example, why is the function called `updateUserStatus` if it is only returning the result of a query? It should also always return an array, for consistency.

Comment: cakephp give me an Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: the response of the method is 0 and not 2 like the value from  [status_id] => 2

Comment: if $trans is the variable you are using, this should work. I checked locally too

Comment: mmm, because i tried to change $transaction['status_id'] : 0, like this,  $transaction['status_id'] : 2; and when i did a echo $currentStatus, return me the value 0 or 2 when I changed